# Does it make sense to use DataLoader without a db?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, prisma-graphql, dataloader

I found out about DataLoader package reading GraphQL [tutorial](https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/1-server/) but all of the [examples](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader/tree/master/examples) for DataLoader package corresponds to some databases.

Does it make sense to use DataLoader if my GraphQL layer is just a layer on top of the REST API?